# Building NSImage from bytes

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im trying to build an NSImage from some strange bytes.
Im using BlackMagic SDK to get the bytes of a recieved frame:

```
unsigned char* frame3 = NULL;
unsigned char* frame2 = (Byte*)malloc(699840);

videoFrame->GetBytes ( (void**)&frame3);
memcpy(frame2, frame3, 699840);

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:frame2 length:sizeof(frame2) ];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];

//(till now i use statically 699840, because i know its size)
```

Why i said the bytes are strange is that the content of the "frame2" looks like this:

```
printf("content: %s",frame2);
```

> \200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200\200.........\200 (to the end)

It should be blank black frame.

Does somebody know how could I figure out something with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use these apis to get an image from data bytes.

NSString *filePath = [yourDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName.jpg"];

[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: I dont want to save the NSImage into a jpg on HDD. I just want to get the frame into NSImage format to continue working with it.